# FB Graph API: Get group wall posts with time posted and number of likes?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

It is a closed group (I am a member and have access to these posts) and so I am using v2.3 as user_group permission was deprecated in newer versions. I only want the past 100 wall posts on this group with only two data entries: time posted and number of likes. This is what I tried-
API explorer-

```
1121167991289664/feed?limit=100&summary=true
```

but this gives me neither past 100 posts (only recent ones with paging parameters) and neither like count.

Here's the output:    http://pastebin.com/Pzefh6Ps

Comment: are you admin of the group? you need to be admin afaik. and then you can use user_managed_groups.

Comment: No, you don't. Not if using 2.3 or older.

Comment: actually, user_groups is part of the 90-day deprecations, so it should not matter which version you are using.

Comment: either way, you should not build something on an API that is deprecated

Comment: Not building anything, just trying to analyse time-like correlation.

Comment: btw, you are not even asking for a like count, so why do you expect it to show up in the result?

Comment: Then how can I ask for it? Googling led me to using the summary parameter

Answer (score 2):

This works fine:

```
group-id/feed?fields=message,created_time,likes.limit(0).summary(true)&limit=100
```

Of course you get the recent entries. If you want to get older ones, check out the paging options in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#paging

Comment: But how to get only the wall posts?

Comment: what do you mean? what else do you get?

Comment: if you want to get the message too, just add the message in the fields parameter. added that to my answer.

Comment: how to get the username along with message too in the feed?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems like it's not possible to get CLOSED groups' posts via Facebook API anymore. At least not if you're not personally an admin in them.